# How to set --work-tree or --git-dir in smartgit?

Tags: git, smartgit

Smartgit creates .git directory in work-tree directory. I want to locate .git directory out of my work-tree directory, how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After creating or cloning your repository, you can move the `.git`-directory structure to somewhere else and instead add a `.git`-file which points to that location. E.g. if you have `git-test-wt` and `git-test-repo` stored side-by-side on your disk, create `git-test-wt/.git`-file with following content:

```
gitdir: ../git-test-repo
```